# Sitemap URL contains /magento How to remove it?

Tags: url

```
Version: Magento ver. 1.9.0.1
```

I'm new to Magento and following a book to optimize SEO settings. During creating a Sitemap generation for Google, it is generating a url:

http://mystore.com/magento/sitemap.xml

My question is how I can remove the `/magento` so it will look like:

```
http://mystore.com/sitemap.xml
```

I've searched google and forum with the terms I could think of like `remove /magento from sitemap url`

but had no luck.. if this is a duplicate please let me know.

Comment: What is your base URL?  Are you using store code in URL's?

Answer (score 1):

You can create site map in magento from admin panel.

Go to `Catalog > Google Sitemap`.

Then click on Add sitemap button at top right hand side, then new window appears with fields `File name`  and `Path` add `sitemap.xml` in file name and `/` in path this will results you `http://mystore.com/sitemap.xml` if your base URL is `http://mystore.com/`

Comment: I've created a Sitemap already. Hence the question, asking about a URL generated after sitemap creation. I get it from your answer that the base URL for my Store must be http://mystore.com/magento. I'll check on it.